# What is lambda doing in this python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to really understand what is happening in this line of python to get it to pull the incoming data to a string instead of writing it to an outfile.

```
ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, lambda s, w=outfile.write: w(s+"\n"))
```

It looks like [retrlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) is getting a command and a callback -- but then there is an additional 3rd argument. What is it doing?

Also, I understand lambdas as explained here (which look very similar to javascript anonymous function callbacks) but don't see how to apply that to this case, where lamda s is defined in the second argument  [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why)

There are too many unfamilar things happening in this python code. Can someone explain what is happening in this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not an optional third argument to the `retrlines` function, but an optional second argument to the lambda.

The `retrlines` function gets passed two arguments:

```
"RETR " + filename
```

and

```
lambda s, w=outfile.write: w(s+"\n")
```